# assets (images,css,js) files are not loading properly in Odoo 11

Tags: odoo, assets

I am trying to install a custom module in our Odoo11 app. The app was installed successfully and was able to access the modules table. But when I tried to access the urls from controllers, it seems that the assets (images,css,js) files are not loading properly.

Steps I followed to install:

1. copied the custom module into the ~/custom-addons
2. Updated the Applist
3. with the Admin account went to Apps and installed the custom module.

Are there any additional steps that I have to do?

Note: It was properly working in the local development server. Problem is when installing in the production server.